# sed more than one number or 'g' in substitute flags

Tags: sed

When I run my command I get:

```
sed 's/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>//2g' all.xml
sed: 1: "s/<?xml version="1.0" e ...": more than one number or 'g' in substitute flags
```

How can I fix this? It doesn't make much sense to me. I'm trying to remove all but the first instance of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` from a new xml file.

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Comment: @thatotherguy imagine the same XML file combined several times. So there are multiple instances of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> `

Comment: Your snippet would require all these instances to be on the same line. Is that what you have?

Comment: @thatotherguy no, separate lines.

Comment: Which OS version and sed version do you use?

Comment: @Cyrus macOS mojave

Comment: You'll find a lot more people willing to read input you provide than imagine input you describe. [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output. See [ask].

Comment: Some call it [summoning the daemon](https://www.metafilter.com/86689/), others refer to it as [the Call for Cthulhu](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) and few just [turned mad and met the Pony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8344060). In short, never parse XML or HTML with a regex! Did you try an XML parser such as `xmlstarlet`, `xmllint` or `xsltproc`?

Answer (score 0):

You `sed` line does not give error on my Ubuntu 18.04, but it does not work. `sed` is very good to work with one line at a time, but harder to get to work across multiple lines.

`awk` may be a better solution.

```
awk '/<\?xml version="1\.0" encoding="UTF-8"\?>/ && f++>0 {next} 1' file
```

This will test your line if it contains the patten and test if flag `f` is larger than `0` and then increase flag `f` by `1`.  So in first hit, the flag is `0` and line is printed.  For all other find flag `f` us larger than one and the `next` makes us skip the line and go to next.   The last `1` is always true, so if its run, do the default action, print the line.